# While loop displaying result 3 times

Tags: php, html, while-loop

Basicly I'm trying to make a simple news feed but I'm stuck at the moment as my while loop display the result 3 times, why is this? :/

```
<?php 
$sql ="SELECT
            *
        FROM
            news,
            admins";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'Error while selecting from database. Please contact the administration team';
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '
        <div class="content_news">
            <h1>' . $row['news_name'] . '</h1>
            <p style="font-size:12px;">Posted by <b>' . $row['admin_name'] . '</b> on ' . $row['news_date'] . '
            <p>' . $row['news_description'] . '</p>
            <a href="' . $row['news_link'] . '">read more</a>
        </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

?>

If you'd like to see what I am talking about: http://freewallpaperblog.com/freshrp/

Ignore the last 2(those are static html not php)

Comment: Because there are three rows of data?

Comment: No there's just 1 row in the database :/

Comment: I don't mean to pry, but have you seen this in the database? Sometimes the simple answers are the hardest to find.

Comment: Can u show us your table rows ?

Comment: You might want to check your SQL - there's no JOIN condition in there, so every row in each table is being joined to every row in all other tables.

Comment: Yeah alright that is the problem, but I have no clue how to JOIN the tables together :(

Comment: @user3112321 - if you can post the structure of your tables, I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: Be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data to be sure you are generating valid HTML, and avoiding certain types of XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query selects data from 2 tables (`news`, `admins`) so it joins every row of 1st table with every row of 2nd table

```
SELECT * FROM news, admins
```

i recommend you to use following query

```
SELECT news.*, admins.admin_name FROM news
INNER JOIN admins ON news.admin_id = admins.id
```

where `admin_id` is your correct column name

Comment: $sql ="SELECT
    news.*,
    admins.admin_name
   FROM
    news
   INNER JOIN
    admins
   ON 
    news.admin_id = admins.id
   ";

Comment: And column = admin_id

Comment: Unknown column 'news.admin_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: can you post your news table structure?

Comment: Alright fixed it - query is:  $sql ="SELECT
    news.*,
    admins.admin_name
   FROM
    news
   INNER JOIN
    admins
   ON 
    news.news_id = admins.admin_id
   ";

Answer (score 0):

You either have 3 admins or 3 rows of news. Your query makes a direct multiplication between tables. Try "left join" instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM news
INNER JOIN admins ON admins.id = news.adminid
```

Or whatever adminid is in the news table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
 SELECT
                *
            FROM
                news
    Inner join admins on news.admin_id = admins.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You made no **JOIN** statement in your SQL, as someone else has already commented on in your question. It would help if you posted the associated fields you're grabbing, but based on your $row keys, my best guess is the following should work for you (but I can't promise it will without knowing how your database is designed, I can only infer from the variable names):

```
$sql = "SELECT news.name, news.date, news.description, news.link, admins.name"
. "FROM news"
. "INNER JOIN admins"
. "ON news.name=admins.name"
```

> References:
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html